# Pull Text from Drop Down Field to Single Line Text Box - SharePoint / Nintex Forms

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, custom-form, nintex

I am trying to pull in the text from a Drop Down field on my Nintex Form into a single line text box within the same Nintex Form. Is there a custom JavaScript code that can be written to accomplish this?

Here is what is a visual:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the JS ID(**Client ID in JavaScript variable**) for the dropdown and textbox field, then use the code like below to achieve it.

```
NWF$(document).ready(function(){
    NWF$('#' + JSID1).change(function(){
        var selection = NWF$('#'+JSID1);
        NWF$('#' + JSID2).val(selection.val());
    });  
});
```

The following articles for your reference.

[Button to Set Field Value (JS)](https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-SharePoint/Button-to-Set-Field-Value-JS/m-p/56697#M46870)

[How to retrieve the values from the drop down control](https://community.nintex.com/t5/Nintex-for-SharePoint/How-to-retrieve-the-values-from-the-drop-down-control/td-p/33294)